# Jenkins declarative pipeline, run the same job on multiple agents

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have three slave nodes and they all have the label "general-slave".

Now this pipeline only select one slave randomly and run the job:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'general-slave' }

  stages {
    ...
  }
}
```

How do I run the job on all three slaves? The stages are long so am trying to avoid repeating.

This might sound straight forward but I can't seem to find a good answer. Thanks!

Comment: take a look here: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/3073/how-to-properly-achieve-dynamic-parallel-action-with-a-declarative-pipeline

Comment: If you want a more declarative approach, have a look at matrix: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-matrix